# Auto kill fastcgi process when deploying django

Tags: python, django, process, fastcgi

Everything goes well days ago. But since today, when I run fastcgi, the process will be killed  by system automatically. The worst thing is I don't know why and which process kill the fastcgi process.

Let me give some detail.

we use nginx to serve static files for another django app which listen to 80 port.(this is for production use)

And we use lighttpd/fastcgi for another two django apps, which listen to 8090 and 8091 respectively.(these are for development test)

the command I run are:

```
python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8090
```

and

```
python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8091
```

after I run one of them, I run *ps -ef|grep "python"* and I can see the process of fastcgi, but seconds later, they are gone.

the output of ps are:

```
root      2685     1  0  2009 ?        00:00:27 /usr/bin/python -tt /usr/sbin/yum-updatesd
root      2827     1  0 03:49 ?        00:00:00 python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8090
root      2828  2827  0 03:49 ?        00:00:00 python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8090
```

and fastcgi is killed and our site is down.

So what should be the problem? How can I figure out?

Thanks.

Comment: belonts-on-serverfault ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your logfiles!

You can make add *outlog* and *errlog* options to the *runfcgi* command to log stderr and stdout to a file. See `python manage.py help runfcgi`.

Answer (score 0):

'lsof -w -n -i tcp:8090' or 'fuser -n tcp 8090' or 'netstat -anp|grep :8090[[:blank:]]' should show you the process ID. If there is no (init)script to use to shut down the offending service (since TCP/8090 means proxy) to kill you can by PID 'kill -9 pidnumber'.